# Pseudocode - Largest to smallest integer

Tags: algorithm

Write a program that will read in five positive integers (one at a time) and print out the largest and smallest number of the five numbers. The program should read the numbers one at a time.

---

Mind you this is pseudocode and not to be done in any language. 
 My question is how would I go about setting this up so that the 5 integers save as values so I can display them.
Don't want the answer, just a start.

Comment: Are you sure you ever saw some kind of program code? This really is one of the simplest tasks to do and I dont think StackOverflow.com is for making other people solving your homework.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming related questions. I would suggest post it on a relevant site on StackExchange if looking for a pseudo-code. Programming puzzles, Computer Science, even Mathematics may be start.

Comment: @gsndev Pseudo-code questions are fine for [so] - I don't think this question belongs here, but not for that reason. Not [codegolf.se], [cs.se] or [math.se] would be appropriate for this question.

Comment: Well, I'd say it's a pretty good beginner question. It's not just a "I-paste-my-homework-here" question, and it states a specific problem, which is a good problem at it (how to store the values, foreshadowing a need for arrays or a specific algorithm). Sure, it's somewhat borderline, but let's not be too aggressive.

Comment: @SáT How is it not a "I-paste-my-homework-here" question? That seems to be exactly what the OP did.

Comment: @Dukeling just thought this question is a good case for problem-solving since the OP wants the answer to be independent of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you read the numbers, keep track of the currently largest and smallest numbers, and update the values as the input is coming in. This has the advantage that it works for even long sequences of numbers. I mean something like this:

```
min = 0
max = 0
while input:
   read number from input
   if number < min:
       min = number
   if number > max:
       max = number
```

Comment: All honesty I was up for 2 days straight and just couldn't wrap my head around this. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

How would you solve the same problem if you had to only report the largest number? The pseudocode would be something like the following

```
consider the first number to be largest 
for each of the rest of the number
  if it is larger then the current largest
    assign to largest
```

How would you do it if there were two?

```
consider the first number to be largest 
if second number is larger then the largest
  consider the second number to be largest, first to be 2nd largest
else
  consider the first number to be largest, second to be 2nd largest
for each of the rest of the numbers
  if it is larger then the largest 
    consider current largest to be 2nd largest and this number to be largest
  else if it is larger then the 2nd largest
    consider it to be 2nd largest
```

But if there are three or more this can get ugly. How do we keep `N` largest number? Clearly, we need a list of `N` sorted number. I will leave it to you how to maintain that list, but here's a pseudocode using that approach

```
 populate the top-list with first N numbers from input, ensure the top-list is sorted
 for each of the rest of the numbers
 if the number is larger then any number in the top-list
   insert it at the right place in top list, pushing out the smallest element of the top list
```

The question now is: **is this better than sorting the list and picking up the top N and bottom N elements?**

The answer is that "it depends". Can you figure out some circumstances where one approach is better then the other?